# Error: Compile Error: Invalid bind expression type of Schema.SObjectField for column of type Id at line 9 column 136

Tags: class

Public class CampaignmemberSa{

```
public lead l{get;set;}
public List<Innerclass> wraplist{get;set;}
public  CampaignmemberSa(){
wraplist= new List<Innerclass>();
}
Public void campaignonchange(){
for(Campaignmember cm:[select id,lead.Status,lead.Company,lead.FirstName,lead.lastName,lead.City,lead.State,lead.Country,lead.leadSource,Contact.status__c,Contact.Company__c,Contact.FirstName,
  Contact.lastName,Contact.City__c,Contact.State__c,Contact.Country__c,Contact.leadSource from Campaignmember where  CampaignId =: lead.Campaign__c]){
   wraplist.add(new Innerclass(cm));
}
}   

Public class Innerclass{
       Public CampaignMember cm{get;set;}
       Public String Status{get;set;}
       Public String Company{get;set;}
       Public String FirstName{get;set;}
       public String lastName {get; set;}
       Public String City{get;set;}
       Public String State{get;set;}
       Public String Country{get;set;}
       public String leadSource {get;set;}
           Public Innerclass(CampaignMember cm){

              this.cm = cm;
              if(cm.Lead.Id != null){
                  this.Status = cm.Lead.Status != null ? cm.Lead.Status : '';
              }else if(cm.Contact.Id != null){
                  this.Status = cm.Contact.status__c != null ? cm.Contact.status__c : '';
              }
              if(cm.Lead.Id!=null){
                   this.Company = cm.Lead.Company != null ? cm.Lead.Company :'';
              }else if(cm.Contact.Id != null){
                   this.Company = cm.Contact.Company__c !=null ? cm.Contact.Company__c:'';
              }
              if(cm.Lead.Id!=null){
                 this.FirstName = cm.Lead.FirstName !=null ? cm.Lead.FirstName :'';
              }else if(cm.Contact.Id != null){
                this.Company = cm.Contact.FirstName !=null ? cm.Contact.FirstName:'';
              }
              if(cm.Lead.Id != null){
                  this.lastName = cm.Lead.lastName != null ? cm.Lead.lastName : '';
              }else if(cm.Contact.Id != null){
                  this.lastName = cm.Contact.lastName != null ? cm.Contact.lastName : '';
              }
               if(cm.Lead.Id != null){
                  this.City = cm.Lead.City != null ? cm.Lead.City : '';
              }else if(cm.Contact.Id != null){
                  this.City= cm.Contact.City__c != null ? cm.Contact.City__c : '';
              }
              if(cm.Lead.Id != null){
                  this.State = cm.Lead.State != null ? cm.Lead.State : '';
              }else if(cm.Contact.Id != null){
                  this.State= cm.Contact.State__c != null ? cm.Contact.State__c : '';
              }
              if(cm.Lead.Id != null){
                  this.Country = cm.Lead.Country != null ? cm.Lead.Country : '';
              }else if(cm.Contact.Id != null){
                  this.Country= cm.Contact.Country__c != null ? cm.Contact.Country__c : '';
              } 
              if(cm.Lead.Id != null){
                  this.leadSource = cm.Lead.leadSource != null ? cm.Lead.leadSource : '';
              }else if(cm.Contact.Id != null){
                  this.leadSource= cm.Contact.leadSource != null ? cm.Contact.leadSource : '';
              } 
           }
}
```

}

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if I helped solving your problem. Else... what's up still there? :) (read: let us know how it went in the end and we'll help you more if needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SOQL at the first lines you are using a bind variable ":Lead.Campaign__c", but there is no context variable initialized with that name - you used name "l". Changing that in the SOQL will fix this specific issue.

In the current implementation, the ":Lead." bind variable is leading Apex compiler to the Lead sObject "static class" (not very correct canonical definition of it), of which Campaign__c is a property returning the Schema.SObjectField token reference to the Campaign__c field.

To be more specific: the error tells "hey, you passed me as bind variable a Schema.SObjectField object, while I need to compare it with an Id - review your code!" (we should have a committe for user friendly error messages as such :)

Comment: Here's more docs on the topic, in case they're needed. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm

Comment: And here it's why "Lead.Campaign__c" returns you a Schema.SObjectField token, whenever there's no initialized variable with "lead" name. https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_Schema_SObjectField.htm#apex_class_Schema_SObjectField and https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm